# Loading big KML file into Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I have a very big **KML file** (around 600mb) of data compacted in a **20mb KMZ** file. This data represents points in a map, each point being a tree inside the city of São Paulo. I'm trying to recriate this map in an Android Application, using the `Google Maps API` and trying to load the `KmlLayer` into it.

**The problem is: Google Maps API only accepts a maximum size of KML file**, and it's <10MB.

I tried loading the KMZ into the map by using

```
layer = new KmlLayer(mMap, R.raw.map_arvores, getApplicationContext());
```

Utility provided by the following package:

```
com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.4
```

but it was completely unsuccesful, the map was displayed correctly, but the green dots that are present inside the KMZ weren't loaded into the map.

**How can I load a big KML / KMZ file into a Google Maps API map?**

Comment: You could  split the kml  .. in several kml < 10mb .. or store the point in a db and build an application with google maps .. .that show only the part of city you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are limits on KML size in Google Maps. The file (KML or KMZ) cannot be bigger than 3MB, and if it's a KMZ, the uncompressed KML cannot be bigger than 10MB. There is also a limit of 1000 features in the KML. More details are available here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#restrictions

You will probably want to consider options for serving subsets of the data to the map, either by splitting it geographically, and thinning it for zoomed-out views, or by using some sort of clustering when zoomed out.